# js corrupt file only working on some pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am making a magento webshop, but i have run into some problems with the theme i am using.

I bought it on themeforest, and i have asked the developer for help, but it takes ages for them to answer and come with a real solution to fix the problems, so now i am seeing if someone here can help me solve the problem.

The webshop: http://new.webhipster.dk/index.php/home-left

When i add items to basket ("Læg i kurv"), it only works on the front page (the link listed above). When i go to another page, it won't add the item to basket. (e.g. http://new.webhipster.dk/index.php/roedvin.html)

So my guess is that there is a corrupt js file, but what i don't understand is, that it is the same code which is generated in header on both pages - but still it doesn't work on any other page but the frontpage.

How do i figure out what js file is corrupt and isn't loaded properly?

I have gone trough each one to see if they load, and it seems like they all load exactly like they do on the frontpage.

Comment: Hey Patrick have a quick look at you browers debug-window and you'll notice an error ' Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function'. Now take a look at the following answer:  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/31496

Comment: @SteveMuster What i don't understand is, that on this page: vinas.dk/roedvin.html the exact same file is used, but here the error does not occur - why does the error happen on the first webshop and not the second? And with the link provided, does this mean i have to find everywhere there is jQuery code and put that inside that scope? This seems a bit harsh

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a library required for it or might be css. As error in your console window say that it could not found css property.
Because when I tried accessing url directly from browser it's adding items into cart

For Example you are calling -

```
setLocation('http://new.webhipster.dk/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL25ldy53ZWJoaXBzdGVyLmRrL2luZGV4LnBocC9ob21lLWxlZnQ,/product/2/form_key/1Tfx79G6V33Q7l2Q/')
```

Now try accessing it from the url something like 
   http://new.webhipster.dk/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL25ldy53ZWJoaXBzdGVyLmRrL2luZGV4LnBocC9ob21lLWxlZnQ,/product/2/form_key/1Tfx79G6V33Q7l2Q/

and this will add item in your cart.

Now you debugging should start from function setLocation(). Try doing file search for setLocation function. and check where it is failing.

Hope this will help you atleast for debugging.